# Why are old initrd files of uninstalled kernels filling up /boot partition?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, kernel

On several Ubuntu machines I am constantly facing the problem of a full boot partition although I always do remove all old kernels. The problem seems to occur, as many `initrd` files are on the boot partition even though the related kernels are not actually installed. To give in example:

```
root@Jacobi:/boot# ls -lah
insgesamt 202M
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 3,0K Jan 30 10:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4,0K Jan 30 10:03 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Dez 11 15:36 abi-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Jan  9 22:28 abi-4.4.0-109-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M Jan 19 14:06 abi-4.4.0-112-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 187K Dez 11 15:36 config-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 187K Jan  9 22:28 config-4.4.0-109-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 187K Jan 19 14:06 config-4.4.0-112-generic
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 1,0K Jan 30 10:03 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  10M Jan 30 10:03 initrd.img-3.13.0-39-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  10M Jan 30 10:02 initrd.img-4.4.0-101-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  10M Jan 30 10:02 initrd.img-4.4.0-103-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  38M Jan 30 10:02 initrd.img-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  38M Jan 30 10:02 initrd.img-4.4.0-109-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  10M Jan 30 10:03 initrd.img-4.4.0-38-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  10M Jan 30 10:03 initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  10M Jan 30 10:02 initrd.img-4.4.0-59-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  10M Jan 30 10:02 initrd.img-4.4.0-77-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  10M Jan 30 10:02 initrd.img-4.4.0-78-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  10M Jan 30 10:02 initrd.img-4.4.0-81-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 179K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8M Dez 11 15:36 System.map-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8M Jan  9 22:28 System.map-4.4.0-109-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8M Jan 19 14:06 System.map-4.4.0-112-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Dez 11 15:36 vmlinuz-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Jan  9 22:28 vmlinuz-4.4.0-109-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6,8M Jan 19 14:06 vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic
```

But only linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic and linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic are installed:

```
root@Jacobi:/boot# dpkg -l linux-image-\* | grep ^ii
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic       4.4.0-104.127 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic       4.4.0-109.132 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic 4.4.0-104.127 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic 4.4.0-109.132 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

If I delete the unnecessary initrd files manually they will be generated again as soon as I try to do an upgrade.

What could be the cause of this issue and how can I get rid of those files permanently?

Comment: How did you remove the packages corresponding to these versions?

Comment: @muru I can't remember having it done in any other way, than to purge them with `apt-get autoremove`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should check partially removed kernels with

```
dpkg -l linux-image-\* | grep ^rc
```

and remove them with for example `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic`.

Purging will remove initramfs generation rules from `/var/lib/initramfs-tools/`.

If it does not help, you can remove them manually from initramfs list:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/initramfs-tools/3.13.0-39-generic
sudo rm /var/lib/initramfs-tools/4.4.0-101-generic
sudo rm /var/lib/initramfs-tools/4.4.0-103-generic
sudo rm /var/lib/initramfs-tools/4.4.0-38-generic
sudo rm /var/lib/initramfs-tools/4.4.0-45-generic
sudo rm /var/lib/initramfs-tools/4.4.0-59-generic
sudo rm /var/lib/initramfs-tools/4.4.0-77-generic
sudo rm /var/lib/initramfs-tools/4.4.0-78-generic
sudo rm /var/lib/initramfs-tools/4.4.0-81-generic
```

Usually I run `purge-old-kernels` followed by `sudo apt-get autoremove` to have only 2 recent kernels.

You can reinstall installed kernels with their initramfses:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall \
$(dpkg -l linux-image-\* | grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: This seems to work pretty well. To sum up: some how there were many only partially removed kernels. I spotted and removed them as described above. Then I had to remove  the unnecessary `initrd` files form boot manually once again to free some space there, et voilà problem solved! Thanks!

Comment: As I've read, it is bad form to use `rm` for anything releated to `initrd` or kernels or headers.  There are some commands available that will handle the removal of partially removed kernels/headers/initrd.img files for you.  See `update-initramfs`.  See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 4):

If you have already used `dpkg` to purge the kernels / headers and if you have already checked `dpkg -l` and still don't see the kernels / headers installed there, but you *still see references to these old kernels* in `/boot` in the form of `initrd-img` files, then the proper way to purge these references and files is with the `update-initramfs` command.

For example, if you only have `4.4.0-109` installed, but you still see the following in `/boot`:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  10M Jan 30 10:02 initrd.img-4.4.0-103-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  38M Jan 30 10:02 initrd.img-4.4.0-104-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  38M Jan 30 10:02 initrd.img-4.4.0-109-generic
```

You can safely remove `4.4.0-104` and `4.4.0-103` from `/boot` with the following commands:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -d -k 4.4.0-103-generic
$ sudo update-initramfs -d -k 4.4.0-104-generic
$ sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
```

The first two commands delete the references to those kernels in `initramfs` generation rules as well as the files in `/boot`.  The last command tells initramfs to regenerate the `initrd.img` files based on the updated rules.

Theoretically you could also use

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -d -k 4.4.0-{103,104}-generic
```

to delete multiple kernels at once, but for some reason this didn't work for me.

Comment: +1 - This is the correct method (and answer) for orphaned initrd's.

Comment: Thank you. Removed excess initrd.img files. Hopefully won't come back