# Is it safe to delete linux header file manually?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg, inode

I recently have inode full issue on a production server. What I have done are:

1. Sort folders according to how many files they have by: `sudo find / -xdev -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1 -n`
2. check the kernel I am using by: `uname -a`
3. See what kernels are using by: `dpkg --get-selections| grep linux`

From step 1, I know there are tons of file in `linux-headers-{version}-generic`. From step 3, I know some of them are not even installed. I have tried `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` and `sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-{version}-generic --purge`. None of them remove anything in `linux-headers-{version}-generic` folder.

What I am thinking is that I might need to delete those folders manually by `rm -rf`. Just want to know if it is safe to do so?

Comment: You will need to purge them individually so that they are removed from the apt database. Are you sure it's only the header? Normally it also have the image, modules and modules-extra.

Comment: @BernardWei When you say purge them, do you mean `sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-{version}-generic --purge`? If this is the case, I did purge them individually. In the sorted folders list, I only saw a lot of files in folders look like `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic`. Did not see any imgae, modules and modules-extra. Maybe is because they do not have tons of files.

Comment: @BernardWei So is it safe to do this: `rm -rf /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-128-generic` if I am sure this kernel is not installed?

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1001292/66509) but change `linux-image` to `linux-headers` for idea of removal with `apt-get`. It is bad idea to manually remove files controlled by APT.

Comment: @MarsLee It's bad practice to remove stuff managed by APT without updating APT database. The proper way is to purge them with apt or apt-get.